# Razor - insert same section more than once

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

In the page:

```
@section NavLinks {
    some content here...
}
```

In the layout:

```
<div class="NavLinks">
    @await RenderSectionAsync("NavLinks", required: false)
</div>
<div id="MainContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<div class="NavLinks">
    @await RenderSectionAsync("NavLinks", required: false)
</div>
```

And results in:

```
InvalidOperationException: RenderSectionAsync invocation in '/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' is invalid. The section 'NavLinks' has already been rendered.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.RenderSectionAsyncCore(string sectionName, bool required)
WebSite.Pages.Shared.Pages_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1() in _Layout.cshtml
+
                    @await RenderSectionAsync("NavLinks", required: false)
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem on my side, it seems that we can't render the same section more than once. As the alternative workaround, I suggest you could try to use the following method to display the content:

1. Using different section name, code as below:

   ```
    <div class="NavLinks">
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Top_NavLinks", required: false)
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div class="NavLinks">
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Footer_NavLinks", required: false)
    </div>
   ```

   and define them in Razor Pages view:

   ```
    @section Top_NavLinks {
        some content here...
    }
    @section Footer_NavLinks {
        some content here...
    }
   ```
2. Using partial view:

   ```
    <div class="NavLinks"> 
        <partial name="_NavLinks.cshtml" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <div class="NavLinks"> 
        <partial name="_NavLinks.cshtml" />
    </div>
   ```

   Then, add some code in the partial view(_NavLinks.cshtml), like this:

   ```
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hyper Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyper Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyper Link</a></li>
    </ul>
   ```

   The result like this:

   [image]

Finally, for using the same section more than once, I suggest you could try to [submit a feedback](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: One big disadvantage of this method is that it's necessary to copy-paste content to both sections.

Comment: Yes, if using a different section name, we have to copy-paste content to both sections. You could consider using the partial view to display the content, thus, we could only add two `<partial>` tag.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to assign the HTML rendered by a section to a variable.

Comment: @user626528 "if it's possible to assign the HTML rendered by a section to a variable" I also check this checked it, but unfortunately, it's still not working. It seems that this is a build-in behaviors. So, at present, you could use the above methods as the alternative workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Is the question specific to section OR a piece of Razor code?
Instead of RenderSection use Partial tag and put your re-usable code in that Partial View.